# Responsive design and content location

Tags: html, responsive-design

I'm using GridSet for responsive design and had a question regarding content location. Imaging I have two columns. The left column contains block A and Block B while the right column contains Block C and a link. The order changes depending on the size in which it is viewed. So we might have the following:

**Mobile:**

Block A
Block B
Link
Block C

**Tablet:**

Block A  |  Block C
Block B  |  Link

**Desktop:**
Same as tablet

Notice how in mobile the link appears **above** block C but in tablet and desktop the link appears **below** block C. So my question is how can I define the content so that it follows these rules?

Comment: in what order are your blocks and links in the HTML?

Comment: Let's say they are ordered like this: <div id="column1"><div id="blockA"></div><div id="blockB"></div></div><div id="column2"><div id="blockC"></div><a></a></div>

Comment: how about using some js/jquery to remove the block and append it back depending on the layout you want ?